# Tool for java execution path analysis

Tags: java, profiling

While determining the impact of various bug fixes, I often find myself trying to find all the routes through the codebase which can end up in my changed code. This is a tedious manual process, involving lots of clicking on method names in Eclipse and searching  for 'References...' while I draw a tree structure of calls in my notepad.

This *seems* like it should be automatable, but whenever I search for such tools I fail to find such a thing. There seem to be tools which will analyse code for bugs, race-conditions, etc (FindBugs, PMD, Checkstyle, for example) but nothing which will simply output potential routes through the code. It's quite possible I'm not using the correct search terms.

Does such a tool exist for Java or I have overlooked a key reason why this is not possible?

Comment: Note that *profiling* usually means analyzing a *running* program. What you're asking is a subset of static analysis (i.e. finding out stuff about a program simply by "looking at it" instead of "running it and seeing what happens"). That might have been a reason why you didn't find the phrase "Call Hierarchy" in your research.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I sort of knew that, but was clutching-at-straws for the nearest term I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a call hierarchy. It is built in Eclipse, IntelliJ and Netbeans.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eclipse+call+hierarchy

Comment: Open Call Hierarchy is Ctrl+Alt+H in Eclipse (at least on Windows).

Comment: That's it! I knew there had to be something. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't the "Open Call Hierarchy" Command what you are searching for?

To use this select a method, field, constructor, etc. and select "Open Call Hierarchy". Here you are able to browse through the places where your code references the selected element.

There is a shortcut, too: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>